# Click to show detail using Jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one question about popup slide. I want to do as in the picture:

[image]

So i am using this for click to show post detail:

```
function getAreaInfo(id)
{
  var infoBox = document.getElementById("infoBox");
  if (infoBox == null) return true;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
    if (xhr.status != 200) alert(xhr.status);
    infoBox.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  };
  xhr.open("GET", "get_post_info.php?msg_id=" + id, true);
  xhr.send(null);
  return false;
}
```

This is link:

```
<a href="get_post_info.php?msg_id=351" class="" onclick="return getAreaInfo(351);" data-id="7"> Click To Show Post Details </a>
```

Showing the details div:

```
<div id="infoBox"></div>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Please stop the looping GIF!

Comment: @forgivenson I want to make collapsible, as shown in the picture.

Comment: Why is this tagged `jquery` when you're just using raw Javascript (e.g. XHR instead of `$.ajax()`)?

Comment: @Barmar Because I'm not very good about it.

Comment: What triggers collapsing the popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I would use a container set to `position: fixed` with a sidebar menu inside set to `position: absolute` and placed off the screen:

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar">
   <div class="sidebar-content">
     ...content...
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .sidebar{
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.sidebar-content{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    right: -200px;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

I would also add the id of the record you wish to pull with ajax as a data attribute on the profile image

```
<div class="profile-photo" data-id="1"></div>
```

Then set up your click events:

First on clicking the profile image, pull the corresponding id and make an ajax call to your database to retrieve the record. On success show the overlay and slide out the sidebar now filled with the content from the database:

```
$(".photo").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).data("id");

   $.ajax({
     url: "your_url.php?="+id,
     type: 'get',
   }).done(function(data) {
      $(".sidebar").fadeIn().find(".sidebar-content").animate({"right":0}, 200).html(data);   
   });

});
```

You can then create a click function to close your sidemenu when you click the background:

```
$(".sidebar").click(function(){
   $(".sidebar-content").animate({"right":"-200px"},200,function(){
      $(".sidebar").fadeOut();   
   });     
});
```

And one to prevent the menu from closing if you're inside the actual menu

```
$(".sidebar-content").click(function(e){ 
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bwms9mu/1/)